# File size limitation for shapefile

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.1

I am going through [File size limitation for shapefile](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37447) ESRI support article (this article applicable for ArcGIS 9.X version not for 10.X ) I know may be same article will applicable for 10.x version

So any update for 10.1 version??

**Purpose:** Above question asked from client, side and I explained and given support article just wanted to know updated information for Windows OS (win 7/8) & Linux.Looking in white paper also (10.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that the shapefile format has not changed since [**this 1998 document**](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I agree with you (but my client wants to see "10.1" version in support article) so the remaining thing will be also same is that true?

Comment: I assume the same applies but if you want the article updated you could try making a comment on it there and/or putting a request to your local support.

Comment: Thanks..Okay contacted ESRI domestic they told that they will update the article..